# How to install a version of MacOs 10.13 but lower than 10.13.4

Tags: macos

I have a trouble, the last version of OSX (`10.13.4`) is incompatible with my system, but I absolutely need `OSX 10.13` to install the last version of xcode who support iOS 11.3. I look in the developer download section of apple (I have an Developer account) but I can find only `10.13.4`.

It's sound completely crazy that we can not find by legal way a previous version of OSX (like `10.13.3`), so maybe I miss something and I open this stackoverflow question.

How developer can test their software on previous release of OSx if it's impossible to find them ?

Comment: Yosemite and earlier are available with a developer account, in the downloads page. Sierra and High Sierra are both available through the App Store. But I doubt you can get an earlier point release. It seems unlikely that 10.13.4 is not compatible with your system, but 10.13.3 is. Regardless, you should ask on serverfault.

Comment: @TheNextman: I confirm you 10.13.4 is not compatible :( anyway for serious development we must always be able to test our product in various point release... this example prove it ! point release is not just sparadra ...